# Why doesn't my pie chart update with the new size?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, pie-chart

I'm working with this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NPCas/).  What I expect to happen is that after the `timeout` waits for a second it calls the function `buildPieChart()` with the new size.  I thought

```
path.exit()
  .remove();
```

Is supposed to remove the old pie chart and

```
path.enter()
  .append("path")
```

should put the new pie chart in it's place.

Why doesn't my new pie chart show up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you don't actually have `.enter()` and `.exit()` selections when updating -- all the data elements are matched to DOM elements as you're not adding or removing any elements from the data.

So all you need to do is handle the update selection as well. In recent versions of D3, the `.enter()` selection is added to the update selection after you append elements, so you can exploit that to make your code more concise. All you need to change is this.

```
path.enter()
 .append("path")
 .attr("fill", function(d, i){
// etc
```

to

```
path.enter()
 .append("path");
path
 .attr("fill", function(d, i){
//etc
```

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NPCas/2/).

Comment: Aww damn, I just learned about this yesterday too.  I should have caught it.  Thanks a ton!